# Huawei P8 lite does not ask for user name password for connecting to WI-FI

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, huawei

I have a Huawei P8 lite with `Android 5.0.1`. My phone is having an issue when connecting to Wi-Fi. But only for my office wifi. For other wifi networks, it gets connected with out any issue.

One thing I noticed is the difference of the Security method. For my office network, it is `802.1 x EAP`. But for other wifi networks to which I have connected my phone, the security method(protocol, not sure about the term though) is some thing else, as I remember it was `WASP`.

Others with some other phones in my office can connect to the wifi network. There are some other Huawei users as well, but with `Android KitKat`, they can connect their phones to the network with out any issue.

Why Cannot I connect to the WiFi network? How can I overcome the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't prompt you, it must be setup manually in Android devices using Settings-WiFi and Add network, then enter the information manually. Enter the SSID manually, then change Security to 802.1x EAP, set EAP method to match your network (probably PEAP, ask your IT dept if unsure), then if 2 Phase authentication or CA certificate is required enter that information (otherwise leave blank), under Identity enter your username typically 'Domain\User' and the Password.

If that doesn't work, you will likely need to contact your IT department for more guidance.